# Spring Data Mongo Linked Document Storage

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a pattern for Spring Data Mongo to support persisting a link to a separate document in separate collection and having it re-hydrate automagically when its pulled back out of the database?

```
@Document
class Person <-- Saves to the Person Collection
  @id
  UUID id
  String name
  Address address 

@Document
class Address --
  @id
  UUID id
  String address1
  ...
```

Calling `save(person)` I'd want the address property in the database to reflect the Address Id, and have the address object persisted to the address collection. When I pull the Person back out, Address would be a fully hydrated (or maybe lazily?) and accessible.

- Spring Data Mongo 3.1
- Spring Boot 2.4
- Groovy 2.5
- JDK11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing Spring Data MongoDB 3.2 only supports linking documents via [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs). Those however follow a fixed structure so that the value representing the link within the target document looks like this

```js
{ "$ref" : <value>, "$id" : <value>, "$db" : <value> }
```

`@DBRef` allows lazy loading via its `lazy` attribute. Please have a look at the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references)

The upcoming **Spring Data MongoDB 3.3** release will extend the support for linking documents to cover the above mentioned use case. Still the linked document needs to be persisted on its own.  `@DocumentReference` allows to link `Address` via the `id` property as outlined below.

```java
@Document
class Person {

  @Id
  String id;

  @DocumentReference
  Address address;
}
```

```js
{ 
  "_id" : "p1457",
  "name" : "...", 
  "address" : "a4711"
}
```

`@DocumentReference` will also support *lazy loading* and can be used to link a collection of documents.
Please find the full documentation [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/main/src/main/asciidoc/reference/document-references.adoc#using-document-references).